# Custom modules for the Apache HTTP: binding an external C library with I/O methods

Tags: c, apache, module

I'm writing a custom module for the Apache Http server : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html

I'd like to use an external library that is able to write files using a custom format. The API for this library looks like:

```
MyFormatPtr format= myformat_openfd(int filedescriptor,const char* mode);
MyFormatPtr format= myformat_open(const char* filename,const char* mode);
(...)
void myformat_close(MyFormatPtr format);
```

while the Apache API writes data using methods like **ap_rwrite** (http://pedrowa.weba.sk/docs/ApiDoc/apidoc_ap_rwrite.html )

How can I bind my library with Apache? Something like:

```
(...)
ap_set_content_type(r,"data");
int fd= ap_r_get_file_descriptor(r);/* <- this is what I need */
MyFormatPtr format = myformat_openfd( fd , "w");
(...)
myformat_close(format);
return OK;
(...)
```

Comment: cross-posted on apache-dev: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-modules-dev/201406.mbox/browser

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP protocol POST is mostly used to send files.
In your case, we need to consider POST for receiving file in module (aka uploading file).

Check this http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/apache_mod/139.htm

First make this function

```
   static int util_read(request_rec *r, const char **rbuf)
   {
     int rc;
     if ((rc = ap_setup_client_block(r, REQUEST_CHUNKED_ERROR)) != OK) {
        return rc;
     }
     if (ap_should_client_block(r)) {
       char argsbuffer[HUGE_STRING_LEN];
       int rsize, len_read, rpos=0;
       long length = r->remaining;
       *rbuf = ap_pcalloc(r->pool, length + 1);
       ap_hard_timeout("util_read", r);

       while ((len_read =
           ap_get_client_block(r, argsbuffer, sizeof(argsbuffer))) > 0) { 
           ap_reset_timeout(r);
           if ((rpos + len_read) > length) {
              rsize = length - rpos;
           }
          else {
            rsize = len_read;
          }
          memcpy((char*)*rbuf + rpos, argsbuffer, rsize);
          rpos += rsize;
      }
     ap_kill_timeout(r);
    }
    return rc;
 }
```

Then insert it in module to see what is coming in POST data.

```
  const char *post_data; 
  //POST data receiving
  if(r->method_number == M_POST) {
     util_read(r, &post_data);
     ap_rputs(post_data, r);  
     return OK;
  }
```

For testing make simple HTML like this

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://192.168.0.35/second" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
 Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
 </form>
 </head>
 </html>
```

Here please update this  action="http://192.168.0.35/second" according to your settings.
Try uploading small files first and then see that there are headers, you need to extract from the POST that are separated by boundry separator value, like file name etc ...

For big file modify the code of util_read, eliminate the memory allocation and write the chunk of data in file in every cycle of while loop.

For Apache 2.2 or higher, comment out the lines in util_read

```
//ap_hard_timeout("util_read", r);
//ap_kill_timeout(r);
//ap_reset_timeout(r);
```